# Keep tooltip within parent container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I cannot figure out a way to keep the tooltip inside the "main-content" container. Here's the code:

```css
.main-content {
  background: #151418;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
[data-tooltip] {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  border-left: 5px solid #000;
  border-right: 5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  left: 0;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  font-family: Consolas, "courier new";
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #657b99;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  z-index: 98;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
p {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Hover mouse <span data-tooltip="Here goes a long text that does not stay inside main-content container">HERE</span></p>
</div>
```

Is there any way to push it back inside?

Or add an max-width to the tooltip somehow? I tried to add max-width, but it didn't work because of `[data-tooltip]`'s `display:inline;`.

(I know that replacing "inline" with "block" would solve the problem with max-width, but I can't do that because I need to keep the text inline...)

Comment: The issue is the positioning property -- when you set the position to absolute, you break the constraints of the parent container. Researching how you can limit it without using javascript, but at least that can give you a direction to start looking.

Comment: @Snowmonkey he can limit it by using overflow-y in css

Comment: I'm thinking of a way to have the text break-line when the text exceeds a certain width. Any ideas?

Comment: DO you need the tooltip to be on a single line?

Comment: No I don't, but I also don't want to have a fixed width because it wouldn't look nice having 250px for one or two words.

Comment: use [bootstrap technique](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)  with new `div` element for tooltip and not `::after`

Comment: I was trying to avoid frameworks but I think I will have a look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to make it word responsive, don't know if is even possible with only css - tooltips are for short mesages.

But it's a start

```css
.main-content {
  background: #151418;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
[data-tooltip] {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    border-left: 5px solid #000;
    border-right: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16px;
    left: 0;
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    font-family: Consolas, "courier new";
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #657b99;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    z-index: 98;
    /* width: 250px; */
    min-width: 200px;
    /* max-width: 400px; */
    height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}
p {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>Hover mouse <span data-tooltip="Here goes a long text that does not stay inside main-content container">HERE</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that it looks obnoxious when I use only two words in the tooltip.

Comment: Pseudos like `::after` are not that easy to manipulate. Personally I avoid them. Take a look at bootstrap tooltips